# How to fit an folium map into a div

Tags: python, html, flask, folium

I want to load a map created with folium into a site that is served by flask.
A Javascript function fetches the map from Flask and inserts it into a div. My Problem is that the map is way larger than the div. How can i make the map fit inside the div?

I already tried the height and width parameter of folium.Map but the behaviour doesn't change.

The `<div>`-Element
[image: The div]

The map inserted into the `<div>` with width 80%.
I have set the  background-color to gray to show that the size of the map.
[image: The map inserted into the div]

Here is an example showing the problem.

app.py

```
import folium
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/map')
def map():
    folium_map = folium.Map(location=[39.750855, -101.533079], width="80%")
    return folium_map.get_root()._repr_html_()
```

templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(128,128,128);">
    <div id="smallDiv" style="height: 40vh; width: 100%; background: aqua;"></div>
    <script>
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch('/map')
            .then(repsonse => repsonse.text())
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById('smallDiv').innerHTML = data;
            })
        }, 3000);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

requirements.txt

```
blinker==1.7.0
branca==0.7.0
certifi==2023.11.17
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==3.0.0
folium==0.15.0
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
numpy==1.26.2
requests==2.31.0
urllib3==2.1.0
Werkzeug==3.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the CSS Shorthand property

```
overflow: hidden
```

To the 'smallDiv' element.

```
<div id="smallDiv" style="height: 40vh; width: 100%; background: aqua; overflow: hidden;"></div>
```